# do scriptures in vernacular languages have phalashruti (benefit from listening/reciting)?

Tags: shruti, phala

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalashruti

Phalaśruti is a Sanskrit compound word consisting of the words phala (lit. 'fruit') and śruti (lit. 'listening'), literally translating to, "fruits of listening".[5][6]

Bhagavata Purana, Ramayana, Vishnu Sahasra Nama, Shiva Purana are examples of scriptures with phalashruti.

Does any merit/benefit accrue from vernacular scriptures like Ram charit manas, kamba Ramayanam, sectarian Tamil scriptures etc.?

Comment: You can yourself check those scriptures you've mentioned to see if Phalasrutis are found in them or not. Unless Phalasrutis are specifically mentioned there is no way to say what are the benefits

Answer (score 1):

Radhe Radhe,

I cannot say for all the examples of scriptures you have listed, but I can speak for Ramcharitmanas. The scripture written by Pujya Sri Gowswami Tulsidaji Maharaj has been given a seal of approval by Kashinath Bhagwan Shankar himself. For many people who are not allowed to/are not able to recite Vedic verses/mantras, it is suggested to recite Ramcharitmanas chupai. It is even said that any one of the seven kand can help you cross bhava-sagar.

Also, all the knowledge of every scripture is found in Ramcharitmans.

I will, however, say that works of great bhakt and saints should typically be studied and recited as they are very dear to the lord and help one attain bhakti and moksha. Not only that, they help understand scriptures easily, but when one attains bhakti and moksha, what more can one need? Even scriptures like Bhaktimal etc. are held in high regard as works of devotees and saints are holy as they host the knowledge of Vedas and all other scriptures.

I will however say don't fall too much into Phalasrutis and focus on developing bhakti and getting moksha as anything else is unnessasary which only traps you in bhav-sagar. However, everyone has different needs and when one wishes for something god always fulfills it and shows path in one way or another.

Even the Pujya Shankaracharya of Puri Peeth suggests normal people read Ramcharitmanas- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsW2A7Rv2Z8&t=287s

Here is Pujya Rambhadracharya on Ramcharitmanas- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdUiUwALaBo

Here is Pujya Shri Rajendradasji Maharaj on Ramcharitmanas- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj6Z8j6d1NY

Forgive me if my answer was not satisfactory enough for you.

Radhe Radhe